# Injections of Sobolev Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I am studying Sobolev Spaces and appear the following question, that look simple, by I do not know how answer it:

If $T>0$ and $k\geq 2$, with $k\in \mathbb{N}$, then $ H^{k-1}(0,T) \subset W^{k,\infty}(0,T)$.

**Why it is true ?**

Comment: I don't think this is true. Can you check again please.

Comment: For me was strange also, but It is true !

Comment: No it is not true

Comment: Could you write some argument of your answer ? @timur

Comment: If it were true wouldn't the fact that $W^{k,\infty}\subset H^{k-1}$ imply that $H^{k-1}=W^{k,\infty}\subset H^k$. Hence by recursion $L^2=C^\infty$ on any real interval.

Comment: @Rem Where I can learn more about it ? what happened if $H^{k-1} \subset W^{k,\infty} $?

Comment: What happens is that $f\in H^{k-1}(0,T)$ is also in $H^s(0,T), \forall s\geq 1$ which is not true.

Comment: Everything is backwards. Even if you keep the regularity index the same, it is not true that $H^k\subset W^{k,\infty}$. Now you have $H^{k-1}$ which makes it even worse.

Comment: @timur what are the correct injections in this case ?

Comment: One correct embedding would be $H^{k}\subset W^{k-1,\infty}$. But I can't guess what your book/teacher wanted to ask since there are many other possibilities.

Comment: @timur could you recommend me some book or chapter topic for understand better this Issue, please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It is not true.** Counterexample: For $x>0$, let $\mathscr I f(x) = \int_0^xf(y)dy$ and consider $G:=\mathscr I^{k-1}g$ where $g(x)=\frac1{x^{1/4}}$. Note $G^{(k-1)}=g\in L^2((0,T))\setminus L^\infty((0,T))$. Easy to check that $G^{(j)}\in L^\infty$ for all $j\le {k-2}$. So $G$ is a function that is in $H^{k-1}((0,T))$ for every $T$, but not even in  $W^{k-1,\infty}((0,T))$, so its not in $W^{k,\infty}((0,T))$.

Comment: Thanks! What about $ H^{k-1}(0,T) \supset W^{k,\infty}(0,T)$ ? is it true ?
there are some kink of Rellich-Kondrakov theorem for the situation with $q=\infty$ and $p<q$?

Comment: @Newinmaths This is true even if you replace $H^{k-1}=W^{k-1,2}$ with $W^{k-0,p}$ because $L^\infty \subset L^p$ on the finite measure space $(0,T)$. For compactness yes RK gives $W^{k-1,p}\Subset W^{k,\infty}$

Comment: How can I prove that ? is possible to use RK with $q=\infty$ ?

Comment: I don't know what you want to prove, but its probably better to ask a new question. When you do that you can paste the link here