# Special case of Rellich-Kondrachov Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I am studying Sobolev Spaces, and I am following the classic book "Sobolev Spaces" by Robert A. Adams and John. J. F. Fournier, 2d edition.

In the page 168, the hypotheses of theorem 6.3 (Rellich-Kondrachov), say that:
Let $\Omega$ be a domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$, let $\Omega_0$ be a bounded subdomain of $\Omega$, and let $\Omega_0^k$ be the intersection of $\Omega_0$ with $k$-dimensional plane in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $j\geq 0$ and $m\geq 1$ be integers, and let  $1\leq p<\infty$.

I am looking for the part II of this theorem, which say that:
If $\Omega$ satisfies the cone condition and $mp>n$, then
$$
W^{j+m,p}(\Omega)\to
W^{j,q}(\Omega_0^k) 
$$
is a compact imbedding if $1\leq q<\infty$.

**Where can I read this kind of result on the case with $p=\infty$? It remains true ?**

Comment: @Calvin_Khor Here is the question that I am looking for

Comment: Can you state RK as in the book, not everyone has this book. If it is what I think it may be, from the conversation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4017912/injections-of-sobolev-spaces/4020242?noredirect=1#comment8299480_4020242), note that $W^{k,\infty}((0,T))$ is a bounded subset of $W^{k,p}$ for all $p$